# My custom post type in WordPress is not showing content through short-code

Tags: html, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

```
function diwp_services_custom_post_type()
{
  $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Services',
        'singular_name' => 'Service',
        'add_new'    => 'Add Service',
        'add_new_item' => 'Enter Service Details',
        'all_items' => 'All Services',
        'featured_image' => 'Add Service Image',
        'set_featured_image' => 'Set Service Image',
        'remove_featured_image' => 'Remove Service Image'

    );


    // Set Options for this custom post type;

    $args = array(
        'public' => true,
        'label'       => 'Services',
        'labels'      => $labels,
        'description' => 'Services is a collection of services and their info',
        'menu_icon'      => 'dashicons-hammer',
        'supports'   => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'capability_type' => 'page',

    );

    register_post_type('services', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'diwp_services_custom_post_type');
```

```
// >> Create Shortcode to Display Services Post Types

function diwp_create_shortcode_services_post_type()
{

  $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'services',
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'publish_status' => 'published',
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) :

        while ($query->have_posts()) :

            $query->the_post();
            $result .= '<div class="card">';
            $result .= '<div class="card-block block-1">';
            $result .= ' <h3 class="card-title">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
            $result .= ' <p class="card-text">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
            $result .= '</div>';
            $result .= '</div>';

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;

    return $result;
}

add_shortcode('services-list', 'diwp_create_shortcode_services_post_type'); 
 
// shortcode code ends here
```

I visited below link and implemented same as that but find no results
[DIVEIN WP](https://diveinwp.com/how-to-create-shortcode-for-custom-post-type-to-display-posts/)

Here is the screenshot as I am working on localhost
[image]

Any help regarding this will be appreciatable.
Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code so the problem is with something else. Have you confirmed the following: is your CPT working correctly, with published posts that are appearing on the website if you use the url? Does the shortcode work if you try it with pages or regular posts? Is WP_Query returning anything at all for your CPTs? That might help narrow down where the problem is, but when we can't see anything apart from the the code you've shown us, there's not much else we can offer.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thanks for the answer, I noticed that the data is coming from the default singular.php file. What should be suitable now to display my custom post

Comment: So you mean that you can see the a published custom post type when you use the url directly? That means your that CPT is working, so now you need to keep debugging to see what *is* causing the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you must fetch permalink from **Setting >> permalink**, and click **Save changes**

Seconds, Now you must add do_shortcode  on the position you need to show all post from custom post type like :

```
echo do_shortcode('[services-list]');
```

I test your code in my end and work good https://abukotsh.me/wp/services/test-service/

Scroll down and you see test services